# Sms/Dialog/Threads view in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How I can create a view/control like in an sms/threads view?I was in searching for it much time, but didn't find anything.

[image: sms view]

Comment: I tried to search this view/control, but can't find it.I need to create dialog view in my application

Comment: yes, in terms of creating this yourself, what have you tried?

Comment: I have all data to fill, but I didn't find this control(sms view)

Comment: Did you try a ListBox Control with a simple DataTemplate ?

Comment: Not yet.How I can get a listbox item like an sms item above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wesevendays: take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6504283/831825), there is a link in my answer to a site where they describe how to mimic SMS bubbles.